# In `aws cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides`, how to pass multiple values to `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::ID>` parameter?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am using [this CloudFormation template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/example-templates-autoscaling.html)

The List parameter I'm trying to pass values to is:

```json
"Subnets" : {
  "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
  "Description" : "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
  "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a list of at least two existing subnets associated with at least two different availability zones. They should be residing in the selected Virtual Private Cloud."
},
```

I've written an utility script that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SUBNET1=subnet-abcdef
SUBNET2=subnet-ghijlm
echo -e "\n==Deploying stack.cf.yaml===\n"
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --region $REGION \
  --profile $CLI_PROFILE \
  --stack-name $STACK_NAME \
  --template-file stack.cf.json \
  --no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
  --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
  --parameter-overrides \
    VpcId=$VPC_ID \
    Subnets="$SUBNET1 $SUBNET2" \ #<---------------this fails
    InstanceType=$EC2_INSTANCE_TYPE \
    OperatorEMail=$OPERATOR_EMAIL \
    KeyName=$KEY_NAME \
```

If I deploy this, after a while my stack fails to deploy saying that a Subnet with the value "subnet-abcdef subnet-ghijlmn" does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to pass parameters to list is to comma separate them

So:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
SUBNET1=subnet-abcdef
SUBNET2=subnet-ghijlm
aws cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides Subnets="$SUBNET1,SUBNET2"
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

Tried every possible solution found online, none worked.

According to the documentation below, you should escape the comma without double-slashes. Tried that, didn't work either.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

What worked FOR ME (apparently this is very environment-dependent) was the command below, escaping the coma with just one slash.

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name teste-memdb --template-body file://memorydb.yml --parameters ParameterKey=VpcId,ParameterValue=vpc-xxxx ParameterKey=SubnetIDs,ParameterValue=subnet-xxxxx\,subnet-yyyy --profile whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-types.html#parameter-type-list)
List/Array can be passed just like python Lists.

```py
'["value1", "value2", "value3"]'
```

Also to note Cloudformation internally used python.