# How to pass list of Refs in CloudFormation JSON?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I used to have a CloudFormation stack which passed VpcId and a `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet>` (list of subnets). but then I decided I actually want my stack to create its own VPC. So I came up with this:

```json
{
  "PublicSubnetOne": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": {
      "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
      "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "AvailabilityZone": {
        "Fn::Select": ["0", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]
      }
    }
  },
  "PublicSubnetTwo": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
    "Properties": {
      "VpcId": {"Ref": "VPC"},
      "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/24",
      "AvailabilityZone": {
        "Fn::Select": ["1", {"Fn::GetAZs": ""}]
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationLoadBalancer" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
    "Properties" : {
      "Subnets" : { "Ref": "PublicSubnetOne,PublicSubnetTwo"}
    }
  },
}
```

This results in the below error:

> Unresolved resource dependencies [PublicSubnetOne,PublicSubnetTwo] in the Resources block of the template

How to correctly pass a `List<>` of Refs to a property?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{"Ref": "PublicSubnetOne,PublicSubnetTwo"}
[{"Ref": "PublicSubnetOne"} , {"Ref": "PublicSubnetTwo"}]
```

When you say `{"Ref": "PublicSubnetOne,PublicSubnetTwo"}`, CloudFormation looks for something with the name verbatim `"PublicSubnetOne,PublicSubnetTwo"`.

You may be confused by this, because [it's totally fine to pass a Parameter with --parameter-overrides (from `aws cloudformation deploy`) with the value `"vpc-someidhere,vpc-someidhere2"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67347160/in-aws-cloudformation-deploy-parameter-overrides-how-to-pass-multiple-value), but it doesn't work that way with refs. I assume CloudFormation formats a comma separated string into a list if a `Parameter`'s `Type` is `List<>`

[There's also an answer that has similar keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52095606/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-strings-as-a-parameter-in-cloudformation) that actually recommends joining (Fn::Join) two IDs together, but I got an error like `Subnets should be List of String` with that